# Solutions to $p_1 + p_2^{a} = p_2 + p_1^{b}$ where $p_1,p_2$ are prime and $a,b$ are positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Solutions to $p_1 + p_2^{a} = p_2 + p_1^{b}$ where $p_1,p_2$ are prime and $a,b$ are positive integers.

Trivial cases are when $a=b=1$. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Other trivial cases are when $p_1=p_2$ and $a=b$. The only nontrivial solution is $(p_1,p_2,a,b)=(3,2,3,2)$, up to symmetry.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that that is the only non trivial solution?

Comment: I can't find the link quickly, but a similar question has been asked in the past, and it turns out that $13^3+3=3^7+13=2200$

Answer (score -1):

**HINT**

\begin{aligned}
p_1 + p_2 ^ a = p_2 + p_1 ^ b &\iff \\
p_2 ^ a - p_2 = p_1 ^ b - p_1 &\iff \\
p_2 ( p_2 ^ {a-1} - 1) = p_1 ( p_1 ^ {b-1} - 1)
\end{aligned}

since $p_2$ and $( p_2 ^ {a-1} - 1)$ are co-primes (as well as $p_1$ and $( p_1 ^ {b-1} - 1)$) it must hold that either

- $p_2 = p_1 \Rightarrow a = b$

or

- $p_2 = p_1 ^{b-1} -1 \Rightarrow \ldots$

Comment: But $15 \cdot 7 = 3 \cdot 35$ and $15 \ne 3$ or $15 \ne 35$

Comment: I don't understand your objection

Comment: $p_2 ^ k$ has only factors $p_2, p_2 ^2 \ldots p_2^{k}$ since $p_2$ is prime. $p_2 ^ k - 1$ cannot have a factor in common with $p_2 ^ k$ (apart from trivial cases $\ldots$) $\Rightarrow p_2 ^ k - 1$ cannot have $p_2, p_2 ^ 2 \ldots $ as factors $\Rightarrow$ $p_2 ^ k - 1$ is co-prime with $p_2$